# How to use state from an input to change cell value in react-tables

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I want a table where cells display dynamic data based on use input. Example:

[image]

By default, cells just show the teacher's name. But if a user selects `age`, cells would display something like `Mrs. J (32)`. If they select `tenure`, the cell shows `Mrs. J (6)`

https://codesandbox.io/s/little-forest-v4o5fc?file=/src/App.js

The part I'm struggling with is how do I get the state from the selection into the `accessor` attribute of `columns`, so that I can dynamically construct the new cell value?

Answer (score 1):

Your CodeSandbox is way too complicated. So I made something very simple with simple data like this:

```json
[
  {
    School: "George",
    Name: "Mrs. J",
    Age: 32,
    Tenure: 6,
    Rating: 4.25
  },
  {
    School: "George",
    Name: "Mrs. L",
    Age: 38,
    Tenure: 12,
    Rating: 4.5
  }
]
```

I used a simple table to display it this way:

```js
  <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>School</th>
        <th>1st Grade</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {data.map((d, k) => (
        <tr key={k}>
          <td>{d.School}</td>
          <td>{d.Name}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Now let's add a simple select button and connect it to a state.

```js
const [sel, setSel] = useState();
return (
  <select
    onChange={(e) => {
      setSel(e.target.value);
    }}
  >
    <option value="">Please Select...</option>
    <option value="Age">Age</option>
    <option value="Tenure">Tenure</option>
    <option value="Rating">Rating</option>
  </select>
);
```

With that, we can conditionally render it on the table:

```js
  <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>School</th>
        <th>1st Grade</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {data.map((d, k) => (
        <tr key={k}>
          <td>{d.School}</td>
          <td>
            {d.Name} {sel !== "" ? `(${d[sel]})` : null}
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here's the full code:

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [sel, setSel] = useState();
  const data = [
    {
      School: "George",
      Name: "Mrs. J",
      Age: 32,
      Tenure: 6,
      Rating: 4.25
    },
    {
      School: "George",
      Name: "Mrs. L",
      Age: 38,
      Tenure: 12,
      Rating: 4.5
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSel(e.target.value);
        }}
      >
        <option value="">Please Select...</option>
        <option value="Age">Age</option>
        <option value="Tenure">Tenure</option>
        <option value="Rating">Rating</option>
      </select>
      <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>School</th>
            <th>1st Grade</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((d, k) => (
            <tr key={k}>
              <td>{d.School}</td>
              <td>
                {d.Name} {sel !== "" ? `(${d[sel]})` : null}
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's a preview:

[image: preview]

Here's the sandbox: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-leftpad-227z4x)

Comment: Thanks @praveen. Any thoughts on how to do it within the react-table library?

Comment: @jack However you're setting the value, send the dynamic value like this.

Comment: @jack I don't understand the code here: `cell.render('Cell')`.

Comment: That would be where the logic exists for dynamically getting the additional data (like age or tenure), depending on the state of the input

Comment: @jack Lemme try with the react tables.

Comment: I was able to get it--I just had to put the state up a level, then pass the event handler to the table. The original thing I missed was adding the filter state as a dependency in the `useMemo` when setting the columns. Thanks for the help